# Creating an App Package through a windows application packaging project fails to copy a dll

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, .net-core, msbuild, cefsharp

I have a newly created (empty) .net core 3.1 WinForm project where I want to use CefSharp. The app in itself runs fine, but I cannot create an app package. I can create an app package if I do not add the CefSharp NuGet package, which makes me think there are some incompatibilities.

Details and step-by-step:

I am using CefSharp.Wpf 83.4.20 in a .net core 3.1 Winform project. To clarify, I have tried using Cefsharp.WinForms as well, with the same result. I use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.6.4.

I install CefSharp as a NuGet, select x64 as a target, compile and it runs fine.

I create a windows application packaging project and add a reference to my app.

The problem arises when I select Publish->Create App Packages; The following warning pops up, and then it terminates with an "Unspecified error occurred":

```
Could not copy "C:\Users\xyz.nuget\packages\cefsharp.common\83.4.20\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.Core.dll" to "obj\x64\Release\PackageLayout\StockCalc\CefSharp.Core.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'obj\x64\Release\PackageLayout\StockCalc\CefSharp.Core.dll' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "MSBuild.exe (13748)" WapProj C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets 3986
```

..it seems the file CefSharp.Core.dll is locked by MSBuild.exe.

This happens even after restarting the computer, using different versions of CefSharp, and installing a few updates of visual studio 2019.

I also tried to reproduce the error with the MinimalExample (CefSharp.MinimalExample) they provide, it compiles fine. I create a windows application packaging project and add a reference to the CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms.NetCore project.

I got exactly the same error here:

```
Could not copy "C:\Users\xyz.nuget\packages\cefsharp.common\83.4.20\CefSharp\x64\CefSharp.Core.dll" to "obj\x64\Release\PackageLayout\CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms.netcore\CefSharp.Core.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'obj\x64\Release\PackageLayout\CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms.netcore\CefSharp.Core.dll' because it is being used by another process. WapProjTemplate1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets 3986
```

The error messages I get are:

```
Error PRI222: 0xdef00001 - Unspecified error occurred. WapProjTemplate1 GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE 1
Error PRI175: 0x8007000b - Processing Resources failed with error: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. WapProjTemplate1 GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE 1
```

Also, when I try to Publish a minimal example, I get these warnings:

```
Warning NU1701 Package 'System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF 2.0.20525' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.netcore ...\CefSharp.MinimalExample-master\CefSharp.MinimalExample-master\CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf\CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.netcore.csproj 1
```

and

```
Warning The plugin credential provider could not acquire credentials. Authentication may require manual action. Consider re-running the command with --interactive for dotnet, /p:NuGetInteractive="true" for MSBuild or removing the -NonInteractive switch for NuGet WapProjTemplate1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets 129
```

I tried to give as much information as possible on this one, as IT HAS BEEN WORKING. I am afraid the error started to happen after some updates of the visual studio, but I have no idea when it started to break.

Thank's for any help with this one.

Comment: I've removed the c# tag and replaced with msbuild. If it worked previously then hopefully someone from MSFT can provide some guidance.

Comment: You could also share a small minimal example with us and it could help us troubleshoot the issue more quickly.

Comment: Try to [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first.

Comment: @Snorvarg, any progress about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle this issue, if you have any concern, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Creating an App Package through a windows application packaging
> project fails to copy a dll

For your first issue,

**first**, please try to [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders)

**then** close VS, use **Task Manager** to kill any VS related process.

**Also**, do not forget to delete `bin` and `obj` folder of the Winform project.

**After that**, restart your project, reinstall `CefSharp.Wpf 83.4.20` nuget package in your winforms project to test again.

> Error PRI222: 0xdef00001 - Unspecified error occurred.
> WapProjTemplate1 GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE 1 Error PRI175: 0x8007000b -
> Processing Resources failed with error: An attempt was made to load a
> program with an incorrect format. WapProjTemplate1
> GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE 1

For the second issue, first you should use make sure that your packing project use `x64` Platform

[image]

**Besides**, before you create the package, you should add

```
<FilterSatelliteAssembliesForMakePri>false</FilterSatelliteAssembliesForMakePri>
```

under the packing xml node of `WapProjTemplate1.csproj` file:

Or you should add like this:

[image]

With the steps, I can create the installer package successfully.

Comment: <FilterSatelliteAssembliesForMakePri>false</FilterSatelliteAssembliesForMakePri> made it finally work! The nuget cache cleanup was good to know about, I have no way of confirming if cleaning the cache was part of the solution or not though. 
Curious, why is settting the flag FilterSatelliteAssembliesForMakePri to false working? I googled it but found only one hit: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/761740/cant-create-app-packages-for-a-windows-application.html